# how to store an array of class in django model

Tags: django-models

Lets say I have to save a class array in a particular class in django.how do i proceed?
for eg.I have a class Books.I wish to store thriller books array in the class books.what is the syntax for Django model and database tables?

Comment: What do you mean by `save class array in class`? You don't save classes - you save objects. And where is your code? What have you tried? Sorry, but your question is unclear and you seem to be missing some fundamentals of Django.

Comment: I have been working on java/hibernate.My query was  like in java(POJO classes) for eg. we have a POJO class Class Company{ int id , String name , Employee[] employee with getter/setter methods}.Employee is another Pojo class with its related data.I want to recode using the django models.How do I proceed ?

Answer (score 1):

Have you read [the Django tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/intro/tutorial01/)? Everything is explained there. The answer may actually depend on the database you are using, though. But assuming you use classical SQL, then here's how ORM works:

1) You define main model:

```
class Company( models.Model ):
    name = models.CharField( max_length = 100 )
    # some other fields if necessary
```

2) You define the corresponding submodel which points to the main model:

```
class Employer( models.Model ):
    name = models.CharField( max_length = 100 )
    company = models.ForeignKey( Company )  # <----- relation here
    # some other fields if necessary
```

3) If you have an object `comp` of type `Company`, then you can access all employers of that company using:

```
comp.employer_set.all( )
```

The `employer_set` property comes from the name of `Employer` class combined with `_set` suffix. You may define your own name for this field. You just need to modify the definition of `Employer` class a bit, like this:

```
class Employer( models.Model ):
    name = models.CharField( max_length = 100 )
    # note the change
    company = models.ForeignKey( Company, related_name = 'employers' )
```

Now you can use:

```
comp.employers.all( )
```

These are the basics. It is impossible (or at least extremely inefficient) for relational database to actually create the array of references in the main model. However that's not the case if you are using some nonrelational database like MongoDB.

Comment: Yes I have gone through the Django tutorial and as well as how the ORM works.My doubt is how do I represent an array of object in database using django models.I am sorry as to I couldn't explain the question correctly earlier.